# Favicon in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favicon

I put `favicon.ico` into `/public/` folder and include the following code into layout page

```
<%= favicon_link_tag %>
```

But inspite of it, the icon doesn't display. What should I do?

Comment: If it's located at `/favicon.ico`, browsers will automatically pick it up; no need for anything in the HTML. If it's not working, either your ICO file is not valid or the browser has cached an old one, try clearing your cache and try again.

Answer (score 26):

I have struggled with the same. This is what worked for me:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

and moving the `favicon.ico` to the /public/images directory.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `favicon_link_tag` is in your app but in general, there are two ways to create a favicon.

1. Put your icon file in your *app root directory* (`/public`). In this case, you don't have to do anything in your code. (does not work in seamonkey, works in all other browsers I know)
2. Place a `link` element in the code of your master view:

   ```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/relative/path/to/file.ico" />
   ```

Comment: [`favicon_link_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-favicon_link_tag) is part of Rails. IE doesn't support PNG favicons.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall gotta love IE. Please check out the edit. The link type in particular.

Comment: It really is ridiculous, I know. I actually use conditional comments to serve up a PNG favicon to "real" browsers, and then an ICO to IE. Also you might want to clarify "root directory", in Rails the app root is different than the public root, which is `/public` and files in there are accessed from HTTP at `/`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall good point. I clarified the answer. Thanks for your valuable input.

Comment: Which one is the root one in this case (rails application): /public/ or exactly the root directory?

Comment: @AlexMaslakov `/public` which is the HTTP root.

Comment: it's best to serve multilayer .ico's to account for retina displays. .ico has the added benefit of you not having to worry about different formats across browsers - http://www.xiconeditor.com/

Comment: @AndrewMarshall could you share the code of how to you deliver .ICO to IE and .PNG to other browsers

Comment: @MauricioGracia Just use [IE’s conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms537512.aspx) to appropriately wrap the PNG `<rel>` tag with a “if not IE” and the ICO one with a “if IE”. Note though that IE10 no longer supports these comments, but PNG favicons are not supported until IE11 `:/`.